# Top Network Posts showing incorrect score

Tags: bug, network-profile, score, top-network-posts

There's a post in my list of Top Network Posts that is showing an incorrect score. The second post listed [there](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/100430/alex?tab=profile) shows a score of 14. But if you actually go to [the post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/deviations-of-ralbag-from-normative-jewish-theology/88099#88099) you see that the score is 15.

This appears to be the only post on the list that has this problem. And on my [Network Profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/9279508/alex?tab=top) it is the eleventh post under Top Answers, and it correctly shows the score of 15.

This is a very minor issue, but any ideas what could be causing it?

---

### Visual Aids:

[image: Screenshot of Top Network Posts]

[image: Screenshot of actual post]

[image: Screenshot of Network Profile]

Comment: Worth noting that this doesn't seem to be a case of delay due to caching (unless the delay is over a month) the last upvote on this post was on August 17th.

Comment: @Catija And for the record, the screenshots are from a week ago, so it's not like it just started showing the wrong score today or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow the database stored the incorrect information for this post, thinking it had a score of 14 instead of 15, which is odd since both locations are fed from the same source, so they should have both matched rather than being different.

Regardless, I had someone "kick off an aggregator sync" and it all reads "15" now.

[image: Post with score of 15 on user's profile]

We're not sure what caused this but it's fixed now! Thanks, Adam!