# Answers in top Network Posts showing incorrect score

Tags: bug, network-profile, score, top-network-posts

There is already a question [Top Network Posts showing incorrect score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315761/357396) which is posted around a month ago (which was fixed). My question reports a similar issue of showing inaccurate scores along with another bug.

A couple of answers in the Top Answers in my network profile are showing incorrect score.

> [image: Answers showing incorrect score highlighted.]

As we can see they are showing a score of 10. But as of writing this question, the score of both the answers is 9. [First answer about marriage](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17397/5212) and [second answer about withdrawing weapon](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17632/5212) both have a score of 9 instead of 10.

Even though the current score is 9, both these answers reached a score of 10 a few months ago and I was awarded [Nice Answer badge](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=5212) for both.

> [image: Image highlighting Nice Answer badges]

The vote was removed either when a user was removed or there was an unupvote. As far as I can tell, I don't remember an unupvote notification in the achievement box from these answers. My guess is the votes are removed when user accounts were deleted.

So, I suspect the score of answers in Top Network Posts is not updated either when there is an unupvote or a vote thrown away due to account deletion.

Is this the right reason why score is inaccurate? Can this be fixed?

Comment: @bob this got nothing to do with sorting. It's a bug with top network posts score. What made you think it's related to the sorting?

Answer (score 5):

***Confirmation***: I'm seeing multiple instances of the same off-by-one problem:

- User [Nog Shine on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/357396/nog-shine)

  - 54 *Was Mjolnir ever used for building something?* ([actually 53](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173891/was-mjolnir-ever-used-for-building-something))
- User [Lun on Ukrainian Language](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/915/lun) top network questions are:

  - 12 *How to transliterate 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation to Latin?*  ([actually 11](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2998/how-to-transliterate-%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87-in-mandarin-pronunciation-to-latin))
  - 8 *How to transliterate 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation to Russian?* ([actually 7](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/how-to-transliterate-%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87-in-mandarin-pronunciation-to-russian))
- User [Ébe Isaac on Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18418/%C3%89be-isaac)

  - 51 *What should I do after advisor got upset when I expressed "belief in evolution" and then said he couldn't add me to his research team?* ([actually 50](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/53885/8469))
- User [M. A. Golding on SciFi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/43538/m-a-golding)

  - 25 *Who was Richard of York at the Battle of Grunwald?* ([actually 24](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/47273/40884))
- User [Patrick Hofman on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245360/patrick-hofman)

  - 82 *How to remove the last element added into the List?* ([actually 81](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23245652/2842962))

It's sporadic: not all posts have these problems.  It affects both questions and answers.