# Incorrect answer score for a top post in my Network Profile

Tags: bug, network-profile, score, top-network-posts

I've experienced the same error described in [Answers in top Network Posts showing incorrect score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318009/259305) for [my answer about the solvability of y = xeˣ](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2701986/290189).  Its score has remained constant at 6 for a long period of time (≥ 1 month), but [my Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3841408/gnusupporter-8964%E6%B0%91%E4%B8%BB%E5%A5%B3%E7%A5%9E-%E5%9C%B0%E4%B8%8B%E6%95%99%E6%9C%83) shows that it has a score of 5 (3rd row from the bottom).

[image]

[image]

From the linked question, it seems that the fix applies only to specific user.  Please give this a fix.