# Top Answers in network profile shows incorrect score

Tags: bug, network-profile, score, top-answers

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353116/798831) post of mine has a score of 13, but the [network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/18074340/ollie) shows that it has 14:

[image]

This seems to be a recur of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315761/top-network-posts-showing-incorrect-score) bug; @Catija's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315764/798831) says it's been fixed.  Can we fix that (again)?

Comment: It was fixed only for that very specific user. Someone should  "kick off an aggregator sync" again to fix your case.