# Period of a few minutes where I was getting error messages with posting and updating a question on this site

Tags: bug, posting

As I was trying to post and update my question [Intermittent problems where I can't get any question search results for just my tags on the Math site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355617/562482), I got several error messages occurring, although the action seemed to have actually worked. First, when I tried to post the original question, I got this:

[image: An error occurred submitting the question]

I assumed it didn't work, so I made a few small changes to the title and then tried to post the question again. This time, I got the following error:

[image: Error saying I was submitting a duplicate question]

When I checked the list of all questions, I found it was already there, so I discarded this version. However, when I went to edit the question and submit the changes, I then got this:

[image: An error occurred submitting the edit]

Nonetheless, when I checked, I found the edit had actually gone through.

Initially trying to post this question on the site caused the same error as the initial one to appear again, so the problem appears to still be occurring, but making an edit just now to this post did work properly.

Comment: Can confirm, it happened when I posted [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355611/top-answers-in-network-profile-shows-incorrect-score)

Comment: WTH?  It gives you errors for posting duplicates?  Never happened with me before...

Comment: @Ollie The error is that my original post *did* go through, so my new question's body text was actually identical to the other one, even though I had changed the title somewhat before trying to resubmit. The system recognized this duplication so it gave that error, correctly in my case since I didn't want to post the same question twice. I'm not sure how robust the check is, so even a minor change in the question text might be enough for it to not notice the duplication.

Comment: Yes, this error resulted in double revisions (hanging web interface, but the edits were actually accepted).