# Slowness or complete failure submitting edits to questions all morning on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, edits

I've noticed these problems all morning. Usually the submission would succeed after a long delay, but recently they have just been failing with an vague `An error occurred submitting the edit` message.

Is there some problem with the website or is it just me?

Comment: Judging from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355617/intermittent-problems-where-i-cant-get-any-question-search-results-for-just-my) post, and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355618/period-of-a-few-minutes-where-i-was-getting-error-messages-with-posting-and-upda) one, no, it's not just you.  I'm getting them too.

Comment: **Update:** Seems much better now, roughly a ½ hour later.

Comment: You can try clearing browser cache for the site (not enough reputations to suggest this as a comment)