# Intermittently receiving maintenance errors on SE network-wide

Tags: bug, search, 500-server-error

[Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355621/slowness-or-complete-failure-submitting-edits-to-questions-all-morning-on-stacko#comment1188669_355621):  Not ten minutes ago, I received this error, twice:
[image]

And also an "Oops, something bad happened" error.  I'm also getting question posting errors.  Can we fix this, please?

Comment: What were you doing when you got the error?

Comment: @AdamLear Question posting errors - I was trying to post [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355611/top-answers-in-network-profile-shows-incorrect-score) question.  Got there eventually, obviously.  The "offline for maintenance" error came up when searching, but both times resolved itself fairly quickly.  The "Oops!" error came up when I went back to the "Active Questions" page.  It looks okay now, though...

Comment: Right on, thanks. We had to perform unexpected maintenance on the search cluster earlier today, so it's possible that had additional repercussions. Glad to hear things seem to be back to normal now.

Comment: @AdamLear Me too ;)  Consider making this [tag:status-completed]?  It's been 'bout an hour since I received any errors, including search ones.

Comment: Actually, looks like we're still working on a few things so I'm gonna untag this for now and follow up in the morning.

Comment: @AdamLear The "... perform unexpected maintenance on the search cluster earlier today, ..." is quite possibly the main reason I was getting search related errors, as I described in my post [Intermittent problems trying to get the correct question search results for just my tags on the Math site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355617/562482). If you haven't looked at that post, I would appreciate you taking a glance through it to confirm those problems are likely due to the search cluster maintenance. Note everything seems to be working for now, starting at around the time of your comment.

Comment: Hey @AdamLear, how do things look?

Comment: @AdamLear 26 mornings later, this is still happening. Any chance to look into it? Thanks! :)

Comment: Apparently we're still experiencing issues with our Elastic cluster. But... it does seem a little suspect that that would be throwing up an error that the whole site is under maintenance.

Comment: @AdamLear Yeah, that's what the other report said, a possible hardware issue.  But it's [tag:status-completed] now.

Comment: The search issues are not 100% done yet. We replaced a bad node today (and have rotated out the bad actor for diagnostics). We'll also be adding more capacity in the overall (hopefully by restoring the bad node to service, once we figure out what's wrong with storage there). It should be much more stable as we've removed the known-bad component affecting 30-40% of all searches on average. We'll also be upgrading Elastic versions in the next week or so to catch up there. It is definitely not anyone's intent for you to see these changes...we just didn't plan on intermittent hardware failure :(